# Finding bivariate probability mass function (by counting?)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose that we role $d$ dice. Let $X, Y$ be random variables, where

$X = \#$ rolled by the die with the highest value.

$Y = \#$ rolled by the die with the second highest value.

By convention, we allow for the possibility that $X=Y$ in case more than one die has the same value (e.g. in a scenario where two dice roll a $6$ and $(d-2)$ dice roll values lower than $6$).

We want to find the probability mass function $P(X=x, Y=y)$. Clearly, $y \le x$, so this eliminates some cases.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& x = 1 & x = 2 & x = 3 & x= 4 & x = 5 & x=6 \\ \hline
y = 1 & & &\\ \hline
y = 2 & 0  & &\\ \hline
y = 3 & 0 & 0 &\\ \hline
y = 4 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
y = 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
y = 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
\end{array}

Basically we want to complete this table. There may be many elegant ways to do this, but I only thought of counting outcomes. For example, there is only one outcome such that $P(X=1, Y=1)$, namely the case in which all dice have the value $1$. This probability is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{6^d}$ (unless I am doing something terribly wrong). Therefore:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& x = 1 & x = 2 & x = 3 & x= 4 & x = 5 & x=6 \\ \hline
y = 1 & \displaystyle \frac{1}{6^d} & &\\ \hline
y = 2 & 0  & &\\ \hline
y = 3 & 0 & 0 &\\ \hline
y = 4 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
y = 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
y = 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
\end{array}

Of course, this was the easy part. Now, to compute $P(X=2, Y=1)$ we consider the outcomes in which one die has value $2$ and all the others have value $1$. Now this part is the one that I am not sure about (I am not very good --a.k.a. terrible -- with counting arguments). My idea is that since we have $d$ dice there are $d$ for us to get one die has value $2$ and all the others have value $1$. So eventually $P(X=2, Y=1) = \displaystyle \frac{d}{6^d}$. This is the same probability $P(X=3, Y=1)$, $P(X=4, Y=1)$

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& x = 1 & x = 2 & x = 3 & x= 4 & x = 5 & x=6 \\ \hline
y = 1 & \displaystyle \frac{1}{6^d} & \displaystyle \frac{d}{6^d} & \displaystyle \frac{d}{6^d}& \displaystyle \frac{d}{6^d} & \displaystyle \frac{d}{6^d} & \displaystyle \frac{d}{6^d}\\ \hline
y = 2 & 0  & &\\ \hline
y = 3 & 0 & 0 &\\ \hline
y = 4 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
y = 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
y = 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
\end{array}

Finally, to consider a harder case, something like $P(X=4, Y=3)$. This is the event in which one die has value $4$, one has value $3$ and the rest can have any value among $\{1, 2, 3\}$. There are $d$ ways to get a $4$ in one of the dice, $(d-1)$ ways to get a $3$ (since one die must be a $4$) and $3^{(d-2)}$ possibilities for the remaining dice. So the probability is eventually $\displaystyle \frac{d(d-1)3^{d-2}}{6^d}$.

Are these counting arguments correct (or, for that matter, my proposed approach) or am I missing something in this process? All comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is an illogical peculiarity of the English language that one says "More than one number is prime." rather than "More than one number are prime." But "more than one number" makes sense, as opposed to "more than one numbers"; hence "die" rather than "dice".  But lots of people are confused about "die"-versus-"dice", so one often sees "dice" used as the singular.  My edit changed "more than one dice have the same value" to "more than one die has the same value". $\qquad$

Comment: I was hesitant myself when writing that particular segment, but since I am not a native speaker of English, mistakes are inevitable. Thanks for pointing that out (and correcting it)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've neglected the possibility of ties and are over counting events where multiple dice equal $y$.

---

You wish to calculate the probability that two dice are $x$ and $y$ and none of the remaining die are higher than $y$.

There are two cases to consider.  When $x=y$ and when $x>y$

- When $x=y$ you want the probability that all dice are at most $x$, minus the probability that one dice equals $x$ and all the rest are less.
- When $x>y$ you want the probability that one die equals $x$ and all the rest are at most $y$ minus the probability that one die equals $x$ and all the rest are less than $y$.

---

> $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X=x,Y=y) & =\begin{cases} { \mathsf P(\bigcap\limits_{k\in\{1..d\}} Z_k\le x) \\- \prod\limits_{i=1}^d \mathsf P(Z_i=x,\bigcap\limits_{k\in\{1..d\}\setminus\{i\}} Z_k< x) }& : x\in\{1..6\}, y=x\\[2ex]\hdashline{ \prod\limits_{i=1}^d~\mathsf P(Z_i=x, \bigcap\limits_{k\in\{1..d\}\setminus\{i\}} Z_k\le y) \\ - \prod\limits_{i=1}^d~\mathsf P(Z_i=x, \bigcap\limits_{k\in\{1..d\}\setminus\{i\}} Z_k< y) } & : x\in\{2..6\}, y\in \{1..x-1\}\\[2ex]\hdashline 0 & :\textsf{elsewhere}\end{cases}\\[4ex]& =\begin{cases} {(\tfrac x 6)}^d - \tfrac d 6~{(\tfrac {x-1}6)}^{d-1} & : x\in\{1..6\}, y=x\\[2ex]\hdashline \tfrac d6~{(\tfrac y 6)}^{d-1} - \tfrac d6~{(\tfrac {y-1} 6)}^{d-1} & :x\in\{2..6\}, y\in \{1..x-1\}\\[2ex]\hdashline 0 & :\textsf{elsewhere}\end{cases}\end{align}$$

Comment: Many thanks for this great answer! I am still having trouble seeing how this result was derived so let me ask an additional question. Suppose we roll $3$ dice (instead of $d$) and we are interested in $P(X=4, Y=3)$. Would it be too much to ask of you to list the outcomes (i.e. the triples of dice values) that we are counting to find this probability? For example we want the outcome $431$ and $432$. Which others do we need?

Comment: @OrestXherija The 15 (of 216) triples of interest would be: $$\{134, 143, 234, 243, 314, \\ 324, 334, 341, 342, 343, \\ 413, 423, 431, 432, 433\}$$

Comment: Many thanks! This clarifies things perfectly!